# Loading database from github

Tags: r, github, download, rcurl

I am trying to download a database stored on Github repository but I totally STACKED.
The downloaded database is empty and has no tables inside.. I am trying to download this on a temporary file, make some operations and delete this database.
Can any1 help me ? I've tried 2 method but non of them worked..

First method syntax:

```
# download database
  library(RCurl)
  options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))
  tmpDB <- getBinaryURL( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pbiecek/archivist/master/backpack.db") 
    tfS <- tempfile()
  writeBin( tmpDB, tfS )
  file.rename(from = tfS , to= "backpack.db")
  tfS <- sub( x = tfS, pattern ="\\\\file.+", replacement="")

  # perform local operations on database

  ...

  # delete downloaded database
  file.remove( paste0( tfS, "\\backpack.db" ) )
  tfS <- NULL
```

Second method syntax:

```
  # download database
  GitUrl <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pbiecek/archivist/master/backpack.db" 
    LocDir <- tempfile()
  # LocDir <- paste0( LocDir, "\\") mb its not neccesary
  download.file( url = GitUrl, destfile = LocDir )

  # operations on database

  # delete downloaded database
  file.remove( paste0( LocDir, "backpack.db" ) )
  LocDir <- NULL
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Your code, specifically your `paste0` calls where you try and construct the URL, don't work. Quotes and commas in the wrong place. Props to @jdharrison for figuring out what you meant there, but you should at least fix that in your Q.

Comment: Was misplacing arguments passed by function on a characters that this will work on that example. Thanks for note, but by the way it was not do hard to guess what that link should look like.

Comment: Having to guess shows a lack of clarity. Not being clear is one of the valid reasons for down-voting (I'm hovering over the down-arrow now).

Comment: Relax mate :) who Cares about those arrows? I'll edit my question if You Have problem with closing apostrophs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `RSQLite` package to access the downloaded database:

```
myFile <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pbiecek/archivist/master/backpack.db"
library(RCurl)
myData <- getBinaryURL(myFile, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
writeBin(myData, 'test.db')
library("RSQLite")
drv <- dbDriver("SQLite")
con <- dbConnect(drv, "test.db")
dbListTables(con)
> dbListTables(con)
[1] "artifact" "tag"
> dbListFields(con, "artifact")
[1] "md5hash"     "name"        "createdDate"
> dbListFields(con, "tag")
[1] "artifact"    "tag"         "createdDate"
```